# how to send an email notification to external users from office 365

Tags: sharepoint, office365

send an automated email notification form workflow to external users.
from office 365.

DOES IT Related to permission issue. This site is an external sharepoint site.

Comment: How should I send an email to external users from sharepoint.

Comment: refer this link. this will help you. --https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rajbugga/2013/10/15/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-send-emails-to-external-email-addresses-sharepoint-2013-workflows/

Comment: link 2 --> https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101744/how-do-you-send-emails-to-external-email-address-in-sharepoint-online-workflows